# exponential moving average taking into account different time intervals

Tags: moving-average, exponential-smoothing

i want to calculate the exponential moving average with the following formula

EMA<sub>t</sub> = val<sub>t</sub> * α + EMA<sub>t - 1</sub> * (1 - α)

but i don't have all the data, i only have some data with a big gap in time. while there are timestamps.

for example timestamps=[43439, 43628, 43753, 43974, 44136] for data=[5, 4, 4, 5, 5]

i used default value for alpha - α = 2 / (n + 1)

but due to uneven intervals it is wrong.

i read about processing incomplete time series - filling with the average, interpolation and so on, but i don't know if it's worth using them - the time intervals are really very large, and the *data depends not only on time*.

i saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023860/exponential-moving-average-sampled-at-varying-times) question, but i don't understand how to get α in a similar way for my case

Comment: It would be nice of you to use capital letters where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace alpha with alpha(t)=exp(-dt/tau) where dt is the time passed between timestamps: dt=t(t)-t(t-1). Here tau is the smoothing constant which has a relation with N: tau≈(N+1)/2.

Then the EMA(t) = alpha*x(t-1) + (1-alpha)*EMA(t-1)

Note that there are 2 separate ways to interpret dt!
1: dt impacts the current value x(t)
2: dt impacts the previous value x(t-1)

This choice depends on your data. Eg for financial data you could assume the price did not change during dt. Than alpha(t) should apply to x(t-1), as is the case in the equation provided.